# SQL Query with clickable URL

Tags: html, sql

Ok, I have a table in SQL that has information like this:

```
ID
Company
Amount
URL
```

I want to create a view on this table that displays the URL but makes the URL clickable.  The URL has http:// in it already but when I query on the table, it doesn't make it clickable.  I have been told I need to use HTML markup in my query but I am unsure how to make this happen.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: DBMS? And what have you tried?

Comment: How exactly are you planning to display these results?  Do you want them clickable from a webpage?

Comment: SQL Server 2012.  The view will be pushed to a website through my CMS.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer to what you are asking:

```
SELECT '<a href="'+ url + '">' + company + '</a>' FROM table
```

However it is a bad practice. You may want to get the URL as is from the database then in your view add it `<a href="HERE">Company Name</a>`

Comment: Tried this but received the error:  Incorrect syntax near '|' and the error: error in SELECT clause:  Expression near '|'.  Unable to parse query text

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to use HTML markup in the URL field, you should rather just store the pure URL in it and use the HTML markup on the webpage itself with the URL from the database.

Anyway in both cases this is the correct HTML markup:

```
<a href="http://paste-your-url-here">Clickable link text</a>
```